# Python: is there a C-like for loop available?

Tags: python, for-loop

Can I do something like this in Python?

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++):
  if someCondition:
     i+=1
  print i
```

I need to be able to skip some values based on a condition

EDIT: All the solutions so far suggest pruning the initial range in one way or another, based on an already known condition. This is not useful for me, so let me explain what I want to do.

I want to manually (i.e. no getopt) parse some cmd line args, where each 'keyword' has a certain number of parameters, something like this:

```
for i in range(0,len(argv)):
    arg = argv[i]
    if arg == '--flag1':
       opt1 = argv[i+1]
       i+=1
       continue
    if arg == '--anotherFlag':
       optX = argv[i+1]
       optY = argv[i+2]
       optZ = argv[i+3]
       i+=3
       continue

    ...
```

Comment: what is it you're actually trying to do?

Comment: updated question with more info...

Comment: There is always `while` for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two things you could do to solve your problem:

- require comma-separated arguments which are going to be grouped into the following option value, you could use `getopt`, or any other module then.
- or do more fragile own processing:

  ```
  sys.argv.pop()
  cmd = {}
  while sys.argv:
      arg = sys.argv.pop(0)
      if arg == '--arg1':
          cmd[arg] = sys.argv.pop(0), sys.argv.pop(0)
      elif:
          pass
  print(cmd)
  ```

Comment: The idea of using argv as a stack is great for my needs, and it removes the indexed based access to the list.

Comment: I love it when people suggest everything but the answer for the question 

Answer (score 24):

Yes, this is how I would do it

```
>>> for i in xrange(0, 10):
...     if i == 4:
...         continue
...     print i,
...
0 1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9
```

**EDIT**
Based on the update to your original question... I would suggest you take a look at [optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html)

Comment: +1 for `optparse`.  Parsing command-line arguments manually is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Apparently optparse is obsoleted in 2.7, and the new flavor is called argparse. 
They both seem to be able to do what I need, but I'm wondering if it's worth the learning curve. Anyway, +1 for pointing out this module.

Answer (score 13):

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   if someCondition:
      i+=1
print i
```

In python would be written as

```
i = 0
while i < 10
   if someCondition
      i += 1
   print i
   i += 1
```

there you go, that is how to write a c for loop in python.

Comment: @Cristi yes but that was in the original example code in the question, so I thought that was what he wanted.

Answer (score 5):

Strange way:

```
for x in (x for x in xrange(10) if someCondition):
    print str(x)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `continue` to skip a value, in both C and Python.

```
for i in range(10):
  if someCondition:
     continue
  print(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't actually need the indices, you probably need the actual items. A better solution would probably be like this:

```
sequence = 'whatever'
for item in sequence:
    if some_condition:
        continue
    do_stuff_with(item)
```

Comment: I would dearly use an iterator over a for loop any time of the day, however I can't think of a way to use iteration in my situation - see updated question

Answer (score 1):

You could first turn the argv list into a generator:

```
def g(my_list):
    for item in my_list:
        yield item
```

You could then step through the items, invoking the generator as required:

```
my_gen = g(sys.argv[1:]):
while True:
   try:
      arg = my_gen.next()
      if arg == "--flag1":
         optX = my_gen.next()
         opyY = my_gen.next()
         --do something
      elif arg == "--flag2":
         optX = my_gen.next()
         optY = my_gen.next()
         optZ = my_gen.next()
         --do something else
      ...
    except StopIteration:
       break
```

Comment: how's that any different than iterating over a list? just more hassle.

Comment: The idea is good, but why convert `sys.argv[1:]` to a generator instance rather than an iterator? E.g. `my_gen = iter(sys.argv[1:])` will get you the same results as your function `g`.

Comment: Also, instead of using `while` with `try: except StopIteration:` a for loop will achieve the same thing. Simply: `for arg in my_gen`. You can still use `my_gen.next()` in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure that an index is incremented within a `try...finally` block. This solve the common problem of wanting to `continue` to the next index without having to copy/past `i += 1` everywhere. Which is one of the main advantages the C-like `for` loop offers.

The main disadvantage to using a `try...finally` is having to indent your code once more. but if you have a `while` loop with many `continue` conditions its probably worth it.

## Example

This example demonstrates that `i` still gets incremented in the `finally` block, even with `continue` being called. If `i` is not incremented its value will remain even forever, and the `while` loop will become infinite.

```py
i = 0
while i < 10:
    try:
        print(i)

        if i % 2 == 0:
            continue

    finally:
        i += 1
```

without it you would have to increment `i` just before calling `continue`.

```py
i = 0
while i < 10:
    print(i)

    if i % 2 == 0:
        i += 1 # duplicate code
        continue

    i += 1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 for i in xrange(0, 10):
    if i % 3 == 0
        continue
    print i
```

Will only values which aren't divisible by 3.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to iterate over something, *and* need an index, use [enumerate()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```
for i, arg in enumerate(argv):
    ...
```

which does the same as the questioner's

```
for i in range(0,len(argv)):
    arg = argv[i]
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem seems to be that you should loop not raw parameters but parsed parameters. I would suggest you to consider to change your decision not to use standard module (like the others).

Answer (score -1):

```
increment = 4                 #say
for i in range(n):
    #write your code here
    n = n + increment
```

This might be the simple solution to the problem if you just want to iterate through the array by skipping 4 members