# for loop with a condition depending on a variable

Tags: python

How to implement a for loop in Python with a condition like in С

```
for (int val = 1; ((double) 4 / val) > e; val = val + 2)
```

I tried to do such a loop through iterators, but as for me, this solution is too cumbersome

```
class Iterator:
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
 
    def __init__(self, e):
        self.e = e
        self.val = 1
 
    def __next__(self):
        if 4 / self.val > self.e:
            self.val += 2
            return self.val
        else:
            raise StopIteration
 
iter_ = Iterator(0.1)
for i in iter_:
    print(i)
```

Is there any simpler analogue, or in such cases the only option is to use a while cycle?

Comment: Looks like it would be easier to use a while loop. Or if you want to use a for-loop, you could use it to iterate over a generator function that contains a while loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: is there a C-like for loop available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354313/python-is-there-a-c-like-for-loop-available)

Comment: If you want to use the loop to generate a list, python has comprehension lists, which include conditions inside the loop. eg: `[a if a else 2 for a in [0,1,0,3]]`

Comment: Wouldn't `for val in range(1, int(4 / e), 2)` work?

Comment: @samwise, range is used only for integer intervals

Comment: This is an integer interval (`val` is an `int` in your C code).

Comment: @Sembei Norimaki, I know there are comprehension lists, but how do you use them in my case when the upper bound is not an integer number?

Comment: I think you need to round up, not down. So instead of `int` it should be `math.ceil`.

Comment: @kari `NumPy` has a function `arange()` that supports decimal ranges

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also just transform the loop condition.

`4 / val > e` is mathematically equivalent to
`4 / e > val` unless val or e are 0.

So then that becomes `val < 4/e` and now we just have:

```py
bound = math.ceil(4/e)
for val in range(1, bound, 2):
  # do some other stuff
```

Comment: this is not a solution, it suffices to consider the case with e equal to 0.1

Comment: @kari Why is this not a solution?

Comment: Well then just do the math and plug in bound = 40 if e = 0.1 is all you need.

Comment: yes sorry i was wrong